# using breakpath command in shell file

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, path

From somewhere I have available in the macOS 10.15.1 Terminal window the command "breakpath", which gives as output the entries in $PATH, one per line. And I can redirect its output, e.g.:

```
breakpath > ~/myPATH.txt
```

If I use it in a bash shell file "~/printpath.sh" such as

```
#! /bin/bash
breakpath > ~/myPATH.txt
```

however, I get an empty file written and, in Terminal, the error message:

```
./printpath.sh: line 2: breakpath: command not found
```

What's wrong?

Unfortunately, as I said, I don't know the source of "breakpath". I tried "man breakpath" but get "No manual entry for breakpath". And when I search my Mac for a file named "breakpath", I find nothing.

Comment: Most probably it's an alias or similar defined in .bashrc. What is the result of `type breakpath`?

Comment: Aha: I find from `type breakpath` result `breakpath is aliased to `tr ':' '\n' <<< "[$PATH]"`, where my actual path appears instead of `[$PATH]`. And I see that using instead of `breakpath` the command `echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"`, with redirection to a file, does work in my bash shell file `printpath.sh`.

Comment: You're welcome. You may also want to change the definition of `breakpath` to delay the expansion of `$PATH`. Right now it seems as if it always uses the value the variable had at the time the alias got defined.